# Timer decrement gets varied for each page load when using back button

Tags: iphone, xcode, nstimer

In my previous question 
[Timer decrement gets varied for each page load](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8600485/timer-decrement-gets-varied-for-each-page-load) 
I got the code working well when I used "Invalidate" and "Release". But when i use a back button the same problem repeats. And i need a stop option too..

```
-(IBAction)back:(id)sender
{

   [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
 }


 -(IBAction)stop:(id)sender
 {
[theTimer invalidate];
[theTimer release];
}
```

this is the code i used here but not working well.

Comment: Thank you all I got it working.. thanks for the replies

Answer (score 1):

Try using it in this way..

```
if ([theTimer isValid]) {
    [theTimer invalidate];
    theTimer=nil;
}
```

And make sure your method is been called.

Comment: used this code. But nothing happens to the timer when i click the stop button.

Comment: you mean your timer is not been stopped, okay then use this code in `-(IBAction)back:(id)sender` method.. before  `-(IBAction)back:(id)sender` line

Comment: WELL  then let's get into detail.. post bit more code like WHERE you have initialize the Timer.. and make sure there is no any recursive call to that method.. Again try finding `theTimer` in your page.. by searching it.. to be sure that there is no any unknown call for this keyword..

Comment: actually in my code  -(void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    count=15;
   theTimer= [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:1 target:self selector:@selector(updateCounter:)userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
    //[theTimer invalidate];
}  i didnt write the left part (theTimer) thats y i got it wrong.

Answer (score 0):

whenever we use timer we must to remember to invalidate timer. when you press back button, your view controller hasbeen change but your timer is still working continue so at back button press you must invalidate timer first. and when you alloc timer first check timer is exist or not, if timer is exist you must invalidate timer first.

```
if(timer)
{
   [timer invalidate];
    timer = nil;
}
```

Comment: no.. the timer is not getting stopped nor getting invalidated. its keep on decrementing even after calling back button.